# 2011 hyundai ix35 2.0 petrol trouble shifting from 1st to 2nd when its still cold

Tags: manual-transmission, transmission-fluid

I have a 2011 hyundai ix35 2.0 petrol. When i start it in the morning it struggles to shift from 1st to 2nd and should you want to gear down from 3rd back to 2nd it is also very sticky. Clutch kit has been replaced as well as the gearbox oil. After it is warmed up the gears are shifting fine. Did anyone had a similar problem and what cou
ld be done to fix it?